# How to connect multiple databases dynamically in apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, dbconnection

I want to connect multiple datasources based on some conditions, i don't want to create multiple `DBCPConnectionPool` services to connect each database, i just want to check if my attribute value is *oracle*, then i have to connect my *Oracle* database by passing *Oracle* configurations like *url* ,*driver name*,*user name* and *password*, if it *MySQL* then i need to dynamically pass *MySQL* related configurations, could you please help with processors which i can use.

I am using `updateAttribute` processor and putting some conditions like below :

```js
Attribute: db.url
Value: ${datasource:equals('Oracle'):ifElse('Oracle-jdbc-url', 'Myslq-jdbc-url')}

Attribute: db.username
Value: ${datasource:equals('Oracle'):ifElse('oracle-username', 'mysql-username')}

Attribute: db.password
Value: ${datasource:equals('Oracle'):ifElse('oracle-password', 'mysql-password')}.
```

so i am not sure how to pass or read these values to DBCPConnectionPool

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DBCPConnectionPoolLookup` controller service for this. You set up `DBCPConnectionPool` instances for each database connection you want, then you add user-defined (aka dynamic) properties to `DBCPConnectionPoolLookup` where the name of the property is the value that the `database.name` attribute will contain, and the value of the user-defined property will be the corresponding `DBCPConnectionPool` instance.

For example, if your `datasource` attribute contains "Oracle" or "MySQL" or something, you can use `UpdateAttribute` to set `database.name` to `${datasource}`, then create a DBCPConnectionPool for your Oracle connection and add a property named `Oracle` to the DBCPConnectionPoolLookup with the Oracle `DBCPConnectionPool` as the value.